# QGIS 1.8 or 2.01 select entries in .shp file that match a field entry

Tags: qgis, select, mac

I've got a .shp file with 40k points (trees) in it. One field is the species name. Is there a way to select those entries that match a desired field name e.g. 'black walnut' so I can move them to a new layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer -> Open Attribute table -> Advanced search. Here in 'SQL where clause' field you enter `field_name = 'tree name'` and hit Ok. Now go Layer -> 'Save selection as a vector file'.

P.S. I bet this question is duplicate